# How do I correct the issue with AppMaker posting to Google Calendar

Tags: javascript, google-app-maker

I am using the Google App Maker template for Calendar.  After creating my own forms and running the script, I am coming up with the below problem.  Suggestions?

> Cannot read property 'validate' of undefined at createEvent
>   (ClientScript:52:13) at
>   Create_Event.Content.Form1.Form1Footer.CreateButton.onClick:1:1

**Client Script**

```
/**
 * Loads Events datasource.
 */
function loadEvents() {
  var ds = app.datasources.Events;
  ds.query.parameters.StartDate = new Date();
  ds.query.parameters.EndDate = new Date();
  ds.load();
}


/**
 * Combines date and time value from date, hours and minutes.
 * @param {Date} dateValue - date object with date value.
 * @param {string} hoursValue - number of hours in string representation.
 * @param {string} minutesValue - number of minutes in string representation.
 * @param {string} dayPart - part of day AM/PM
 * @return {Date} combined date and time value
 */
function getDateValue(dateValue, hoursValue, minutesValue, dayPart) {
  var d = new Date(dateValue.getTime());
  d.setHours(hoursValue + (dayPart === 'PM' ? 12 : 0));
  d.setMinutes(minutesValue);
  return d.getTime();
}


/**
 * Clears form widgets after adding a new event.
 * @param {Object} formWidgets - widgets of form.
 */
function clearFormValues(formWidgets) {
  formWidgets.NameTextBox.value = null;
  formWidgets.StartDateDateBox.value = null;
  formWidgets.EndDateDateBox.value = null;

  formWidgets.StartHoursDropdown.value = 1;
  formWidgets.StartMinutesDropdown.value = '00';

  formWidgets.EndHoursDropdown.value = 2;
  formWidgets.EndMinutesDropdown.value = '00';
  formWidgets.ColorDropdown.value = '0';
}


/**
 * Sends request to create Calendar event.
 * @param {Widget} createButton - widget that triggered the action.
 */
function createEvent(createButton) {
  var form = createButton.root.descendants.CreateEventForm;
  if (!form.validate()) {
    return;
  }

  var formWidgets = form.descendants;
  var startDate = getDateValue(
    formWidgets.StartDateDateBox.value,
    formWidgets.StartHoursDropdown.value,
    formWidgets.StartMinutesDropdown.value,
    formWidgets.StartTimeDropdown.value);

  var endDate = getDateValue(
    formWidgets.EndDateDateBox.value,
    formWidgets.EndHoursDropdown.value,
    formWidgets.EndMinutesDropdown.value,
    formWidgets.EndTimeDropdown.value);

  if (startDate > endDate) {
    formWidgets.EndDateDateBox.validationErrors = 
      ['Event start time must be before event end time'];
    return;
  } else {
    formWidgets.EndDateDateBox.validationErrors = [];
  }

  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function() {
      clearFormValues(formWidgets);
      app.datasources.Events.load();
    })
    .withFailureHandler(function(err) {
      console.error(err);
    })
    .createCalendarEvent(
      formWidgets.NameTextBox.value,
      startDate,
      endDate,
      formWidgets.ColorDropdown.value);
}
```

**Server Script**

```
/**
 * Creates Calendar event.
 * @param {string} title - title of new event.
 * @param {number} startDate - numeric value for start date.
 * @param {number} endDate - numeric value for end date.
 * @param {string} color - value code of event color.
 */
function createCalendarEvent(title, startDate, endDate, color) {
  var event = CalendarApp.createEvent(
    title,
    new Date(startDate),
    new Date(endDate),
    {
      guests: Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()
    });

  if (color !== '0') {
    event.setColor(color);
  }
}


/**
 * Gets Calendar events.
 * @param {Query} query - data query with parameters.
 * @return {Array<Event>} events from Calendar.
 */
function getEvents_(query) {
  var startDate = query.parameters.StartDate;
  startDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

  var endDate = query.parameters.EndDate;
  endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 1);
  endDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

  if (startDate.getTime() > endDate.getTime()) {
    return [];
  }

  var results = [];
  var events = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().getEvents(startDate, endDate);
  events.forEach(function(item) {
    var event = app.models.Events.newRecord();
    event.StartDate = item.getStartTime();
    event.EndDate = item.getEndTime();
    event.Title = item.getTitle();
    event.Color = item.getColor();
    results.push(event);
  });

  return results;
}
```

Comment: I would provide your scripts (both client and server if applicable), otherwise it would be hard for anyone to help you.

Comment: I'm going to guess that since you created your own form for this the form that contains your button is probably not named 'CreateEventForm'. So the line that says `var form = createButton.root.descendants.CreateEventForm` needs to be changed to reflect the name of your actual form.

Comment: I used my own button, and then after the error posted, I used the exact same button on the sample app, both buttons received the same error.  The button on the sample is actually CreateButton and the onClickEvent is CreateButton(widget), but that does not fix the issue.

Comment: This is the line where the error is showing up on the debugger.  Where is the error though?

```
if (!form.validate()) {
    return;
  }
```

Comment: Yes, but your error happens at the line where it says !form.validate(), and it is your form that is undefined because descendants.CreateEventForm is an undefined widget. What is the name property of the form that creates the event? That is what needs to replace ‘CreateEventForm’.

Comment: Just to summarize, it is the line of code prior to the one that is throwing the error that is the cause of that error.

Comment: I have looked it over 20 times, all the names are correct.  Does it matter that it is a popup?  That is the only difference right now.

Comment: If it’s a form inside a pop up it should still be fine, however if it’s just the inputs inside another type of container there is a chance that the validate function is simply not available.